# Excel VBA issue - PasteSpecial (error 461)

Tags: excel, vba

I really hope someone can help me with this issue. I have implemented a button in my workbook which works the following way:

1. The users select a cell or range of cells in the sheet
2. The user click on the button and enters a percentage
3. The cell or range of cells are then changed by the percentage value

The problem is, that the VBA code below works in most of my workbooks, but not all of them. The code is the following:

```
Sub Change_x_percentage()

Dim factor As Double
factor = InputBox("Enter the percentage change")

factor = 1 + (factor / 100)

Sheets("Financial items input").Range("B34").value = factor
Sheets("Financial items input").Range("B34").Copy

ActiveSheet.Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
      SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get the following error message: "Method or data member not found (Error 461)" and "Selection" is highlighted.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be causing this issue in some of my workbooks ?

BR.
Mikkel

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `ActiveSheet.`

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
                       SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tim. I have tried removing the ActiveSheet as suggested. Unfortunately I am still getting the same issue. Any other suggestions ? Kind Regards. Mikkel